# How to hide bottom mobile navigation on desktop?

Tags: reactjs

i am using boostrap class that hides elements on different screen sizes, in this case i'm trying to hide it on desktop and tablets.

heres the code:

```
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid bottom-navbar .d-xxl-none .d-xl-none .d-lg-none .d-md-none">
    <Box sx={{ width:600, height:500 }}>
      <BottomNavigation
        showLabels
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
      >
        <Link to="/profile" className="nav-link">
          <BottomNavigationAction label="Acount" className="bottom-icon" icon={<AccountCircleIcon />} />
       </Link>

       <Link to="/WishList" className="nav-link">
          <BottomNavigationAction label="Wishlist" className="bottom-icon" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
       </Link>

       <Link to="/TrackOrder" className="nav-link">
       <BottomNavigationAction label="Category" className="bottom-icon" icon={<CategoryIcon />} />
       </Link>

       <Link to="/TrackOrder" className="nav-link">
       <BottomNavigationAction label="Track Order" className="bottom-icon" icon={<LocalShippingIcon />} />
       </Link>

       <Link to="/TrackOrder" className="nav-link">
       <BottomNavigationAction label="Search product" className="bottom-icon" icon={<FindInPageIcon />} />
       </Link>
       
       
      </BottomNavigation>
    </Box>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BottomNavigationBar;
```

the problem is that the buttom navbar still display on desktop.
please kindly help

Answer (score 0):

On your div, change your classes from:

`<div className="container-fluid bottom-navbar .d-xxl-none .d-xl-none .d-lg-none .d-md-none">`

to:

`<div className="container-fluid bottom-navbar d-xxl-none d-xl-none d-lg-none d-md-none">`